# How To develop One's Interest in Programming

Tags: lesson-ideas, programming

My younger brother is having a hard time learning programming. This seems strange because he's very good at other computer related subjects. He isn't choosing any other field, so how can he develop his interest towards Programming?

He is also very good at calculations and is interested in football.

Comment: You still don't have enough information here to provide help. How old is your brother? What sort of difficulties is he having? Is he taking a course or just learning alone?

Comment: I think this could be a very interesting question, but like Buffy said, you haven't provided enough information for us to be able to help you. Also why is it imperative that your brother develop his interest? Why is it up to you?

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to know how to answer your question because you don't provide some important details.  However I'll try anyway.

One resource I've heard of is [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/).  Scratch is an interactive, on-line learning lab where people of all ages can experiment with building simple programs with the Scratch programming language.

There is a good list of alternatives to Scratch [here](https://www.educationalappstore.com/blog/alternatives-to-scratch/).  Some of the alternatives they list are:

[Snap](https://snap.berkeley.edu/snapsource/snap.html)

[KODU](http://www.kodugamelab.com/)

And several others as well.

You might also try out [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/).

Good luck!  If you can provide more details it'd help us to give you a better answer!

Answer (score -1):

Don't force your brother towards programming. First of all you should know his interest. Find he is interested in which area of computers. Everyone differs in their approach towards computer. Someone likes computer repairing, troubleshooting, programming... There's lots of interesting things about computer. Not only programming. Ask him about his interest.